# Application is returning errors when trying to load the root path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wrote a simple javascript file that allows me to see the values inside of a database via web browser. It was working before but now it is returning the following error:

```
_http_outgoing.js:494
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:494:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:501:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (issuesDB/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (issuesDB/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (issuesDB/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (issuesDB/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at db.all (issuesDB/app.js:23:21)
    at Statement.errBack (issuesDB/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:16:21)
```

I am pretty sure I did not change anything in the code or on the DB, so unsure why it is now failing, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const sqlite = require('sqlite3');
const db = new sqlite.Database('./issues.sqlite');
const dbname = 'issueInventory';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4001

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));


app.get('/', (req,res,next) => {
  db.all(`select * from $dbname;`,
    {
      $dbname: dbname
  },
  (err,rows) =>{
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(`Something went wrong, we are working on it`)
    }
    res.status(200).send({issues: rows})
  });
});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Application Server listening on ${PORT}`)
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is like you return two responses. You missed the `return` statement.

```
if (err) return res.status(500).send('Something went wrong, we are working on it');
res.status(200).send({issues: rows});
```

Comment: Indeed - now it is back up and running! I also removed the placeholder for the table name, guessing it did not like that part either. Thank you much

Comment: Glad to help :)